# Vuex | What options can we pass to the commit method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

If you take a look at the Vuex `commit()` function, [you can see that it accepts a third argument named `_options`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L74). I am used to set it sometimes with `root: true` when I need to commit a mutation from a module while I am already inside one.

```
commit('main/toggleMenu', { menu: 'right' }, { root: true })
```

I can't find any documentation on this parameter. Do you know what all these options are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html) for `commit`:

> `options` can have `root: true` that allows to commit root mutations in namespaced modules.

So it appears that is currently the only option you can pass to the `options` parameter.

Comment: export interface CommitOptions {
  silent?: boolean;
  root?: boolean;
}

You can also do silent according to the typing